# OOP - CRUD or Use-Cases?

Tags: oop

What is the difference between CRUD and Use-cases in Object Oriented Programming?
I'm making numerous objects and I want to know which one is faster to use. 
Which one is more efficient, and which one is easier to use?

Comment: This is apples vs. trucks comparison. There is absolutely nothing in common between those terms. Clarify what you mean by those terms. And "efficient" and "easier to use" are extremely ambigous and opinionated terms.

Comment: This question makes no sense and as such cannot really be answered in a sane way. Which one is more efficient, and which one is easier to use? A car or a building?

Answer (score 1):

CRUD is short for Create - Read - Update - Delete.

Use-cases, like it is written, are **cases** in which you **use** your system.

So CRUD may be part of an use-case.

For example, a Library Management System may have some use-cases like, Creating User, Deleting User, Update User info, Querying user's info, lending book, returning book, subscribing, unsubscribing ...

The 3 core parts of an use-case: `use-case's name`, `use-case's participants` & `use-case's description`. But depend on the specific organization, use-cases may be extended to contain more than just three core parts.

Below is an example of an use-case. As you can see in the description section, it is CUD.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

CRUD by itself is not any use-cases at all. 
Usually an use-case will perform none, one or many CRUD operations to be able to succeed in the result expected.